# How to capitalize the TextField value first letter of the first word after full stop "."?

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield

Is such a thing possible?

example: "My favourite film is the matrix. And i think... "

similar questions have been asked before but they are forsimple capital the first letter of first word and not more

this codes just worked for first letter of first word and cant understand "."

```dart
extension CapExtension on String {
  String get inCaps =>
      this.length > 0 ? '${this[0].toUpperCase()}${this.substring(1)}' : '';

  String get capitalizeFirstofEach => this
      .replaceAll(RegExp(' +'), ' ')
      .split(" ")
      .map((str) => str.inCaps)
      .join(" ");
}
```

```dart
class CapitalCaseTextFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    return TextEditingValue(
      text: newValue.text.inCaps,
      selection: newValue.selection,
    );
  }
}
```

```dart
TextFormField(
   inputFormatters: [
            CapitalCaseTextFormatter()
                  ]
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this for capitalize each sentence first word

```
extension CapExtension on String {
  String capitalizeSentence() {
  // Each sentence becomes an array element
  var sentences = this.split('.');
  // Initialize string as empty string
  var output = '';
  // Loop through each sentence
  for (var sen in sentences) {
    // Trim leading and trailing whitespace
    var trimmed = sen.trim();
    // Capitalize first letter of current sentence
    var capitalized = "${trimmed[0].toUpperCase() + trimmed.substring(1)}";
    // Add current sentence to output with a period
    output += capitalized + ". ";
  }
  return output;
}
}
```

// Text input formatter

```
class CapitalCaseTextFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    return TextEditingValue(
      text: newValue.text.capitalizeSentence,
      selection: newValue.selection,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: this is not working for me, in `inputFormatters: [ CapitalCaseTextFormatter() ]` Only one letter can be typed inside `TextFormField`. like: "A."

Comment: when I set it to `_contentController.text.capitalizeSentence` it's work. but generate sentense like this: Heey. How. Are. You?.

Comment: i think you got some thing wrong, this is not hepped

Comment: @Husen found your problem because after every word it calls the capitalizeSentence and ended up with dot(.) you can call with `TextInputFormatter`

Comment: I think its have to listen to typing ".", do not add "." to the end of the sentence.

Comment: @Husen create a separate question with your code and error?

Answer (score 1):

Add `textCapitalization` property

```
TextFormField(
   textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
   inputFormatters: [
            CapitalCaseTextFormatter() //no need of it then
                  ]
)
```

Comment: How I can do it in real-time when typing inside `TextFormField`?

Comment: adding textCapitalization reflect the changes when you are typing and start a new sentence.